# Banner on Wordpress site has stopped working

Tags: wordpress

I've taken over managing a Wordpress site with a custom theme based off Underscores.me. I haven't had too many problems with it but recently I added a page (something I've done before with no problem) and later I noticed the banner/slider went black. I did not change the code in the editor and even went back and checked it with a copy of the code I made but didn't see any changes. I'm not sure if this is a theme/plugin issue but I haven't added any plugins. 
The site is integratedneurologyservices.com

Comment: Thanks for sharing the site URL; can you share the exact page you're having this issue on as well?

Comment: There is display:none in flexslider.css line number 49. This might be useful. Also there is javascript error in console and other HTTPS issue.

Comment: @Leland It's not working on any of the pages.

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli I thought it was working but when I removed it, slider photos were stacked up at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[integratedneurologyservices.com](https://integratedneurologyservices.com) looks like it was just recently moved onto an https:// domain. There are still resources called on the site that have an http:// protocol, one of which is jQuery, in the footer. Most web browsers block insecure scripts being called on a secure domain.

If you change that jQuery http:// protocol to https://, the banner will work.